# How can I Remote Access an IIS7 service with IIS Manager?

Tags: iis-7, remote-access

I'm trying to remote access an IIS7 machine, in our LAN. When i start IIS Manager, I do not have the *Connect to a Server* option .. as shown in the diagram, below.

Anyone know how I can get this to show? What setting do I need to install? Powershell script, anyone?

Cheers :)

[alt text http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/wpnew/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/Dave_IIS7/remoteiis7admin16.png](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/wpnew/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/Dave_IIS7/remoteiis7admin16.png)

Comment: what are you running as a client? do you have RSAT installed?

Comment: @Nick Kavadias : RSAT ??? (maybe that answers my question ... ??) Client i'm using? same as the image above -> IIS Manager (as stated in the OP).

Comment: RSAT: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en  client as in client OS

Comment: RSAT has all the remote tools *except remote IIS management*. SeeCarlosAG's answer below.

Comment: @Nick Kavadias -- Ahh! gotcha. Win7 Enterprise x64. But yeah, CarloseAG's answer is the magic winning ticket. Cheers everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running in a client SKU (Windows Vista or Windows 7) you need to install support for Remote Management:
x86:
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9655671
x64:
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9655672

Also make sure the server enables Remote Administration (WMSVC) by: Inetmgr.exe -> Server -> Management Service... enable remote connections and start the service. also make sure to make it auto-start inside the Services snap-in so that if you reboot the service, WMSVC comes back.

More info: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/158/remote-administration-for-iis-manager/